# How to print original color output using subprocess.check_output

Tags: python

I have bunch of executable running GTEST.

GTEST gives color output of passes and failes tests.

Now when I try to run bunch of executable using python subprocess.check_output script it is printing without color.

Here is code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
       try:
           print subprocess.check_output([os.path.join(root, file)], shell= True, )
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
            error +=1
print error
```

Can anyone please help me, How I can print output as  original output with colors?

Answer (score 1):

Since I run in a similiar problem today on windows. I did a little resarch and it seems, that the problem is, that gtest creates the colors within the console by using the screenbuffer handles. The plain outstream of gtest does not contain any color information. That means that the color is lost as soon as these are redirected.

The following code worked for me:

```
subprocess.check_call(["cmd", "/c", gtest_case_executable, "--gtest_color=yes"])
```

as long as the Python command line call was not executed with any redirectioning calls like `tee` or `>>`.